AWS EC2 Spring boot JDBC connection to RDS always resolving to local IP
I have a strage error.
I have an EC2 instance with internal IP 10.10.11.6
I also have an RDS DB with some aws provided url and can resolve to internal IP 10.10.1.124.
From the EC2 instance i can do mysql -h {aws-rds-host or ip} and successfully connect to the mysql instance.
When i do the config properties like below:
  datasource:
    password: <password>
    username: <user>
    url: jdbc:mysql://<aws-rds-hot or ip>:3306/nssf_ussd?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

I get an error that says java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'admin'@'10.10.11.6'
I've checked env configs, there are no conflicting variables.
If i update the username i can see the access denied error is updated with the new username meaning its picking the correct application properties but it keeps insisting on the internal ip for the instance as host even if i explicitly state the other IP.
here is what is interesting, if i put a different host like a randon makamuevans.com, it fails with error of unknown host.

The error message is saying that access is denied for the combination of user=Admin and Source IP address = 10.10.11.6. It is saying it's not letting you login from the EC2 instance. It is not displaying the IP of the host. (As to why it is not letting you login, I don't know.)

It is a problem with your credentials. I think you need to check your username and password.
